# freebsd NFS /etc/exports

Tags: freebsd, nfs

There are 2 directory in /vol. (test1 test2)

I wish it can work like this:

/vol/test1 -ro 192.168.31.111

/vol/test2 192.168.31.111

but it got error:bad exports list line.

Is that any solution can let it work?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Please try to add mask to your IP.
I think file /etc/exports  must be something like this:

> /vol/test1 -ro -network 192.168.31.111/32
>
> /vol/test2 192.168.31.111/32
>   #

You can read more on official exports manual: https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=exports